# how can I create a Single Entity from two other tables/Entity JPA hibernate making a INNER JOIN result with a common key

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

How can I create a Single Entity from two other tables/Entity in JPA/hibernate making a INNER JOIN result with a common key. I was using the below code but it gives me a full join instead of an inner join. it give me records from the meal table even if the
"id 1" does not exist in the allergies table, example:

```
{id=1, name='tacos', description='Mexican food', price ='10',peanuts=null, celery=null, sesameSeeds=null}
```

How can constrain to don't return any records if the 'id' is missing from the secondary table allergies? to show only records when the primary key is present in both tables.

I want something like this instead:

```
{id=1, name='tacos', description='Mexican food', price ='10',peanuts='no', celery='no', sesameSeeds='no'}
```

Please advise.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "meal")
@SecondaryTable(name = "allergens", pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "meal_id"))
class Meal {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    String description;

    @Column(name = "price")
    BigDecimal price;

    @Column(name = "peanuts", table = "allergens")
    boolean peanuts;

    @Column(name = "celery", table = "allergens")
    boolean celery;

    @Column(name = "sesame_seeds", table = "allergens")
    boolean sesameSeeds;

    // standard getters and setters

}
```

Comment: Could you post the code you used to fetch the data?

Comment: The short answer is you can't. `@SecondaryTable` cannot be used for this purpose. Use an optional `@OneToOne` to an `Allergies` entity.

Comment: I made more research and the issue is that it's giving the secondary table as "optional = true" but I need "optional = false" for the secondary table, please help.